# protobuf: string content is overlapped when 2 different instance of the same message in multithread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, protocol-buffers

Recently I encountered a protobuf problem that the string was overlapped. The scenario is :

1/ defined a message like in proto file.

```
message fund_inout_rsp {
  uint64 seq_no = 1;
  uint32 err_id = 2;
  string err_msg = 3
};
```

and then convert this message to C++ code using protoc --cpp_out。
so I got a class named fund_inout_rsp.

2/ Now there are two thread A and B.
In thread A,

```
fund_inout_rsp instance1;
instance1.set_err_msg(u8("123456789"))
instance1.SerializeToArray();
send out by TCP
```

In thread B,

```
fund_inout_rsp instance2;
instance2.set_err_msg(u8("abcd"));
instance2.SerializeToArray();
send out by TCP
```

3/ the TCP receiver got a message.
"abcd56789" 
it seems that the instance1's err_msg is overlapped by instance2's err_msg.
The following is the auto generated code by protoc.

```
fund_inout_rsp::set_err_msg(const char* value) {
  err_msg_.SetNoArena(
  &google::protobuf::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(),
  std::string(value))
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both thread A and thread B touch the same object, `instance2`. Without synchronization, I presume. In that case, your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race.

Comment: It's my writing miss. Thread A only use instance1. I am wondering if there is a data race in the protobuf layer?

Comment: There isn't. We routinely use protobuf library in heavily multi-threaded code. The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown. You aren't serializing into the same array, are you?

Comment: I defined a static template function to do the serializing. In this function, there is a stack array char* buf[2028] = {0} and then serialize to this buffer.

Comment: Show the actual code, don't describe it in prose. `char* buf[2028]` doesn't make much sense - it's an array of pointers, not an array of bytes. What are all these pointers pointing to?

Comment: That can't compile. You have a statement in the middle of a class definition, outside of any function. Don't paraphrase - show the actual code. Ideally a [mcve]

Comment: Code is
    template<typename pkg, typename type> class send_pb {
    static bool snd(const type &p) {
    char buf[2048] = {0};
    pkg* psnd = (pkg*)buf;
    p.SerializeToArray(pkg->body, 2048-1);
    psnd->len = p.ByteSizeLong
    send(psnd);
}
}

 pkg struct is: 
{
len;
body[0];
}
the invoker is like:
auto ret = send_pb<pkg, pkg_type>::snd(pb_pkg);

I will look into if they are serialized to the same buffer as you advised.

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your suggestion, finally it is found that we serialize to the same array. thanks again.